# How to change encoding of a web page retrieved by Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, encoding, simple-html-dom

I am trying to read contents of a web page

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/somepage.aspx');
```

Since the page's encoding is Windows-1254, and I work on a page encoded as UTF-8, I cannot replace some words which have language-specific characters.

For Example:

If I try to

```
$str2 = str_replace('TÜRKÇE', 'TURKCE', $str);
```

it does not replace.

I have tried `htmlentities()` function, It worked but deleted some words which contains special characters.

Comment: Have you tried this: `str_replace('T&Uuml;RK&Ccedil;E', 'TURKCE', $str);`

Comment: @RyanNaddy Yes I have tried it. Doesn't return

Comment: It sounds like a job for [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting strings I have used `iconv('Windows-1254', 'utf-8', $str)` function (thanks to [@pguardiario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966023/pguardiario)). This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Work in utf-8 only. If you have some data in other encodings, convert it. If you does not know the encoding, try to define it. If you cannot, use users. Then use mb_* functions only for all string operations, It is important! some functions is not present in native php, but search its hand-make realizations on php.net/.. in comments.